# Two Absolute Divs Top and Bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, absolute

I have two divs that are absolute.. I want div1 to be on top and div2 to be under it.. div1 may change in size depending on the data in it, and I want div2 to be able to go with div1 accordingly.

[image]

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Here is the styling I have for div1:

```
.div1{
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 width:55%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

How can I put it where div2 will be under div1 and stay under it depending on how big or small div1 gets?

```
.div2{
 width:55%;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
}
```

If javascript needs to be involved, PLEASE only give javascript.. NOT jquery.

Comment: and why both need to be absolute? and if you really want absolute, simply wrap them inside a container and make the container absolute

Comment: @TemaniAfif.. I realize I can do a container that is absolute and it should work fine. I'm wondering what I can do if both divs were absolute.

Comment: Why absolute ? is it really necessary to use it ? two block level elements without no any position rule set to them should work the way you want, and if you want them to be absolute positioned you can wrap them into a div and give position: absolute rule. Don't use `position` rule **unless you know what it does !**

Comment: it's good to wonder but you should first have a good reason to do .. if not, no need to complicate I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `offsetHeight` of the first div element like so:

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2');

console.log(div1.offsetHeight);

div2.style.top = div1.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.div1{
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid green;
 text-align: center;
 width:55%;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.div2{
 width:55%;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think a more accurate way is to do `top of div1 + offsetheight of div1` in case div1 has top different from 0

Comment: @TemaniAfif div one has a top rule set to zero, but in theory you are correct.

Comment: @Neal.. Thanks for actually answering the question. *thumbs up*

Answer (score 2):

Set `position: absolute` to a parent:

```
<div class='div'>
  <div class='div1'></div>
  <div class='div2'></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.div {
  width: 55%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

div1 { ... }
div2 { ... }
```